# SSRS schedule "Maximum request length exceeded"

Tags: reporting-services

I have RDL file that is 107KB long, it works fine in Report Builder 3.
Also works fine on report server but, when a user goes to subscribe, it tells them the max size is exceeded. I would rather not edit Webconfig to try and get this one report working, as that could cause bigger problems. 
I tried renaming it, chopping some stuff out, reducing the time duration, moving the parameter order,using Visual Studio to re-save it I searched here and there doesn't seem to be any solution offered.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, unless you can make the report smaller than 4mb you will have to modify the web.config file.

> The default value of the property MaxRequestLength is 4 Mb. When you upload a report or create a subscription, if the report size is higher than this value, you will bump into this error.

[See this article for more information.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mariae/2009/12/23/error-maximum-request-length-exceeded-in-reporting-services/)